# Elsevier Reference Style

Tags: citing, elsarticle, journal-publishing

In one of my reviews I got this comment from the reviewer:

> "There is some ambiguity in the in-text citations for two references on page 10. More than one reference from the same author(s) in the same year must be identified by the letters 'a', 'b', 'c', etc. placed after the year of publication [Elsevier's Standard Reference Styles]."

How do I give this a,b,c after the year of publication?
If I set `year={1998}` to `year={1998a}` in the BibTeX item, the citation becomes `Author, 998a` from `Author, 1998`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you post an MWE showing this issue? I've used `year="1998a"` before and it worked.

Comment: You can find instructions at [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a different `*.bst` file that solved the issue.
At first I was using `model1-num-names.bst` file for referencing. Changed it to `model2-names.bst`.
Both of these were obtained from Elsevier website.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to modify the year fields manually. BibTeX -- based on the formatting instructions obtained from the bibliography style file -- should be adding the `a`, `b`, etc labels automatically.

A full MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{author:1998:first,
  author = "Anne Author",
  title  = "First Thoughts",
  year   = "1998",
}
@misc{author:1998:second,
  author = "Anne Author",
  title  = "Further Thoughts",
  year   = "1998",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

\begin{document}
\citet{author:1998:first}; \citet{author:1998:second}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```